# How do I turn on sign in from different locations for Windows live messenger

Tags: mac, windows-live-messenger

For windows live messenger, where is this option at? I found it once and I turned it off but I want to turn it back on now but I cannot find the checkbox for the life of me.

Edit - I am on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

Under `Tools / Options / Sign In / Sign in at more than one place`, check/uncheck the following option as required:

[image]

Comment: I am using a mac and I have tried to find this but could not. I have tried preferences but it is not in there either. Do you know where I can find this on a mac?

Comment: Wish you had mentioned that in the question or via a tag. I'm not sure, will need to look around and see if I can find anything.

Comment: let me know if you can't find it, I will look for a windows machine to do the change if it comes down to it